# Need to set col-lg-** col-md-** col-sm-** col-xs-** for every cols?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

This might be a too simple question, I couldn't find the answer yet.

I often use same setting for some monitar size.

In this case, I made like this ,

```
 <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-8 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4">
```

However it is too long and redundant.

Is there any class to say it in a word??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of redundancy in your classes there. Remember that Bootstrap is mobile first so:

```
col-xs-4 col-md-4
```

Is the same as just:

```
col-xs-4
```

So you can shorten yours to:

```
col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4
```

Comment: THanks I see it means that smaller tag could be valid for bigger size.